# Rails, permissions denied cache with Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I have to migrate my local rails app from a Mac environment to Windows. When I try to start the server (rails s) and load localhost:3000, I get the following error:

> Permission denied @ sys_fail2 -
>   (C:/Users/admin/Downloads/botletter-app-fixbotletter/botletter-app-fixbotletter/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/ZQ/ZQEk-QQnRdRsRI3FXTsyFOn0v_aNG5ia5qhyfA2q25U.cache.63832620.11100.334275,
>   C:/Users/admin/Downloads/botletter-app-fixbotletter/botletter-app-fixbotletter/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/ZQ/ZQEk-QQnRdRsRI3FXTsyFOn0v_aNG5ia5qhyfA2q25U.cache)

I understand it's a permission error and searched on the internet to solve it but couldn't find a solution. I'm not really familiar with Windows, any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try  `rm -rf tmp/cache` in your project directory

Comment: I get "rm is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file